# Using Api v2 on android virtual device

Tags: android, maps

Can I use the APIv2 maps on android virtual device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not possible to run APIv2 maps on Virtual Device. You need to test map on real device.
[Go through](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api) this link. You will understand everything.
Why you want to use APIv2?  You can use APIv1 it's working on Virtual device.

Comment: i don't understand why i wouldn't work ?

Comment: Yet it's not possible to run  on virtual device. This feature Google  will add. now you can work with APIv1.